# Correct foreign keys for has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created two tables - `employees` and `tasks`. Each one has the association `has_and_belongs_to_many`, since employees can have multiple tasks and vice versa.

How do I add my foreign keys? Do I add a foreign key referencing the other model to each model?

Answer (score 1):

To handle this N-M relationship, you would typically create an additional table, say `employee_tasks`. This is called a junction table.

The junction table has a column that references the primary key of the employees table, and another column that refererences the primary key of the tasks table.

Typical SQL DDL:

```
create table employees (employee_id int primary key);
create table tasks (task_id int primary key);

create table employee_tasks(
    employee_id int,
    task_id int,
    primary key (employee_id, task_id),
    foreign key (employee_id) references employees(employee_id),
    foreign key (task_id) references tasks(task_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add foreign keys to the join table in migration

```
create_table :employees_tasks, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :employee, foreign_key: true
  t.belongs_to :task, foreign_key: true
end
```